# The file in the bucket cannot be viewed in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

The file( inventor factory design file - zip archive file ) that was visible in the viewer became invisible

When I delete the file and translate it again, I still can't see it.

But when I upload the same file to the new bucket and translate it, I can see it in the viewer

What would be the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the translation might have gone wrong after the update and from then on, the **Viewer** relied on cached information to show the model.

You could try to **delete the manifest** of the file before translating it again or **force the translation** using `x-ads-force` header

Also, **clear the browser cache** as a test to make sure you are looking at up-to-date content

See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-keeps-showing-old-model

Comment: Thank you for your reply

I wonder if the existing Bucket file is suddenly not shown. I never modified the file.

We are showing a lot of model files in Bucket. 

But this sudden loss of files in Bucket can cause serious problems

Are there any other causes?

Comment: Is the file also deleted or just its derivatives (e.g. the SVF generated for it?)
Files can get deleted automatically depending on the retention policy of the bucket: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/